# Advice - Real time data processing from client to server

Tags: real-time, event-driven, data-stream

I am looking for advice/guidance on how to achieve the following:

I have a circuit mounted and connected to an Arduino and I am able to easily retrieve data from it, using Python and the pySerial module. It allows me to determine the value of an analog input over time.

At the moment I am storing that data to a file, with a time stamp and the correspondent value and I would love to hear opinions and thoughts on how I could 'share' this data to a web server and 'play' it live.

Is it possible to 'stream' the values into the dump file and retrieve data from it at the same time through an AJAX request or should I look into event-driven web servers like 'Tornado', 'Twisted'...

I am a bit lost here. Just for the record, I am comfortable with PHP and JavaScript for the final output, I just don't have a clue on how to constantly 'stream' the data I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very open ended. If you could be more specific about what the data is and how you are intending to display or use it on your website, it might be possible to help provide advice or guidance. Please elaborate on the details. Give specifics about the deployment as you envision it (for example, why is this not on the webserver itself so you can just use the file/data directly?)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan to update the Ardunio device too much then it would make sense to have the Python component continue to collect the data over the serial port and publish it in a way that can easily be consumed by a service which can distribute the information in a more efficient, and probably flexible, manner.

e.g.

1. read the data from the serial port and publish messages onto a message queue. The message  queue can then be read by any other component and the data can then be distributed to other applications/clients.
2. Make a web call to a server that can process each update and distribute to other applications/clients.
3. You could use something like [Pusher](http://pusher.com) (who I work for) and make a call to the REST API to deliver each message to any connected clients. Whilst this is a good way of distributing your data you will be publishing your data even if no clients are listening so I think you are best to get the data to a component like a web server first.

Assuming you go with 1 or 2, you can then use [realtime web solution](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide) to distribute the data to any number of clients. You could use Pusher here or you could use a self hosted solution.

So, the data flow as I see it would be:

Ardunio -> small Python app -> Queue (or HTTP request to Web server) -> Realtime Web Technology -> Many clients

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is a small project of my own, so there are no limitations. I only used Python since it was the easiest way to save data via the Serial port. However, your first paragraph sounds very interesting: sending it directly to a defined endpoint (web server). I can change the code in the Arduino and the data is meant to be public.
Could you please elaborate on sending this data from my Serial port to an endpoint? 

As for the comment above, it's an Arduino, so it has to be on my local computer. Looking forward to hear from both of you. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Does your Ardunio have an ethernet port? If so you could make a web request whenever new data becomes available: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient Or are you restricted to the serial port?

Comment: Oh, not really. I could get the Ethernet Shield, but for now I'm suck with the Serial port...and the only shield I was thinking to add to it would be the Motor Control Shield.